# mysql time zone: different column value changes after changing time zone

Tags: mysql, timezone

MySql: changing time_zone from +00:00 to SYSTEM,
one time column changed 5 hours, another time column changed 4 hours, vise versa. both are timestamp.

```
mysql> desc foo;
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id                 | bigint(10)    | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| time               | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| time1              | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select @@time_zone;
+-------------+
| @@time_zone |
+-------------+
| +00:00      |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, time, time1 from foo where id=1;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | time                | time1               |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2021-03-01 05:00:00 | 2021-03-26 04:55:21 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set time_zone='system';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, time, time1 from foo where id=1;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | time                | time1          
|
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 2021-03-26 00:55:21 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Mysql version: 5.7.11